# largest number of consecutive square-free positive integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The question reads

> What is the largest number of consecutive square-free positive integers?

Square-free means that the prime number decomposition of, say $n$, is

$$
n = p_1^{\alpha(1)}p_2^{\alpha(2)}\dots p_k^{\alpha(k)},
$$

where every $\alpha(j)$ is either zero or one. Digging in the book, I have a possible answer: $(2*3**5*7*11*13,2*3**5*7*11*13+1)$, but I don't know how to prove the statement.

Answer (score 7):

Since one of the numbers $n,n+1,n+2,n+3$ must be divisible by $4$, $3$ consecutive squarefree numbers is the maximum. However, there can be arbitary many consecutive numbers that are NOT squarefree.

Comment: This is essentially the only exception.  Aside from these gaps that are forced by small primes, we can fill all the other slots with squarefree numbers.  For instance we can always find $n$ such that $n, n+1, n+2, n+4, n+5, n+6$ (all except $n+3$) are simultaneously squarefree.  Similarly, longer almost-chains are possible once we leave out spaces for multiples of $4$, $9$, etc.

Answer (score 4):

$1$, $2$, $3$ is a sequence of three consecutive square-free integers. Can one do better? No multiple of $4$ is square-free....